# Find results older than 2 days from date in SQL

Tags: php, sql

In my database, I record the date the entry was made.  I want to find entries which are 2 days earlier or older.

I've tried the following which doesn't work properly.

```
//Order is over 2 days old YES
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d"); 
$todaysDatePlusDelay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todaysDate. ' + 2 days'));
```

With the SQL code

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date >= $todaysDatePlusDelay") or die("error");
```

Can I just do all of this in SQL?

Date is shown in this type of format `2017-07-10`

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: You're adding 2 days to today then looking for an order greater than or equal to that?  Is it possible to have a future order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
WHERE o.date <= curdate() - interval 2 day;
```

Also, are you sure you don't really want `-` instead of `+`, to get data from the previous two days rather than the next two days.

(And use mysqli_ instead of mysql_.)

Comment: date is the date the entry was made.  I need two days or more after this.  Future orders are impossible.  Which is correct?

Comment: @user2203466 . . . Same idea but slightly different logic.

Comment: Okay sorted!  Thank you!!

curdate() >= date + interval 2 day